# Select most recent rows - last 24 hours

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
col1  | col2 | col3 | t_insert
---------------------------------
 1    | z     |     |2018-04-25 17:23:46.686816+10
 1    | zy    |     |2018-04-26 18:53:46.686816+10
 2    | f     |     |2018-04-26 19:23:46.686816+10
 3    | g     |     |2018-04-27 17:23:46.686816+10
 2    | z     |     |2018-04-27 18:23:46.686816+10   
 4    | z     |     |2018-04-27 20:13:46.686816+10
```

Where there are duplicate values in col1 I want to select by most recent timestamp and create a new column (col4) and insert the string 'update'.

Where there are not duplicate values in col1 I want to select the value and insert the string 'new' into col4.

Also I only want to select rows that have a timestamp from the last 24 hours.

The expected result:   (This result dosen't show select rows from last 24 hours)

```
col1  | col2 | col3 | t_insert                     | col4   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
 1    | zy    |     |2018-04-26 18:53:46.686816+10 |update  |
 3    | g     |     |2018-04-27 17:23:46.686816+10 |new     |
 2    | z     |     |2018-04-27 18:23:46.686816+10 |update  | 
 4    | z     |     |2018-04-27 20:13:46.686816+10 |new     |
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: the date in col3 is 2018-04-26 not with in 24 hours.

Comment: Yes I know, you did not read my question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, window function can help here:

```
select col, col2, col3, t_insert,
       (case when cnt > 1 then 'update' else 'new' end) as col4
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by col1) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by t_insert desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where t_insert >= now() - interval '24 hour'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```